# gem install compass not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, compass

having trouble running the line gem install compass in terminal. It's returning the following error. Is anyone able to help out with this problem?

> ERROR:  Error installing compass:
>         ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
>     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150225-51908-cfetpz.rb extconf.rb
> checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
> necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
> details.  You may need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>   --with-opt-dir
>   --without-opt-dir
>   --with-opt-include
>   --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>   --with-opt-lib
>   --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>   --with-make-prog
>   --without-make-prog
>   --srcdir=.
>   --curdir
>   --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
>   --with-ffi_c-dir
>   --without-ffi_c-dir
>   --with-ffi_c-include
>   --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
>   --with-ffi_c-lib
>   --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
>   --with-libffi-config
>   --without-libffi-config
>   --with-pkg-config
>   --without-pkg-config
> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in
> ```
>
> `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
>   (RuntimeError)
>       You have to install development tools first.
>         from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in`
>   try_cpp'
>         from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in
>   `block in have_header'
>         from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in`
>   block in checking_for'
>         from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in
>   `block (2 levels) in postpone'
>         from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`
>   open'
>         from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in
>   `block in postpone'
>         from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in`
>   open'
>         from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in
>   `postpone'
>         from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in`
>   checking_for'
>         from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in
>   `have_header'
>         from extconf.rb:16:in`'
>
> ```
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/ffi-1.9.6 for inspection.
> Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/extensions/x86_64-darwin-10/1.9.1-static/ffi-1.9.6/gem_make.out
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is

```
(RuntimeError)
   You have to install development tools first.
```

If you're on OS X (my best guess from the output) you need to install the Xcode developer tools first. You can do this with the command: `xcode-select --install`.

Comment: Hi @Aaron – I've tried running that and got the message –

xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Updates" to install updates

But there doesn't appear to be any updates.

Comment: That is odd. Do have the rest of Xcode installed? What version of OS X are you on?

Comment: – hi @Aaron, I think so(how would I tell?). Bit new to all of this. I'm on 10.10.2

Comment: `Cmd`+`Space` should bring up Spotlight. Try typing "Xcode" in there and if it's found, you have it installed. Otherwise install it from the Mac OS X App Store.

Comment: – yep it's there and installed.